# Ignore asterix(*) while doing diff in Linux

Tags: linux, diff

I am trying to use the standard diff command in Linux inorder to find differences in 2 files.The contents of the file are as follows:

File1

```
Jim
Jack
Tracy*
Michelle
```

File2

```
Jim
Jack
Tracy
Michael
```

diff File1 File2 gives me the following :

```
< Tracy*
< Michelle
---
> Tracy
> Michael
```

However,I want diff to ignore the asterix(*) and give the following output :

```
< Michelle
---
> Michael
```

Is it possible to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using ShinTakezou's approach, but this time using `sed`:

```
diff <(sed 's/\*$//' file1) <(sed 's/\*$//' file2)
```

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
diff -I '*$' FILE1 FILE2
```

> -I RE --ignore-matching-lines=RE
>
> Ignore changes whose lines all match RE

Note: this only works with line ending asterisks.

Comment: Does not work ...  diff -I '*$' File1 File2
3,4c3,4
< Tracy*
< Michelle
---
> Tracy
> Michael

Comment: Did you missed the asterisk after `-I`?

Comment: maybe the reason is here http://www.gnu.org/software/diffutils/manual/diffutils.html#Specified-Lines  --- I've tried and not missed the asterisk and confirm it does not work as expected intuitively.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a diff that has not the `-I` option you can grep away lines containing stars into temp files and then diff the temp files. If you are using bash you can use "two pipes", but if you have it likely you have the diff with the `-I` option too. Anyway it would be

```
sed 's/*$//' file1 >file1.temp
sed 's/*$//' file2 >file2.temp
diff file1.temp file2.temp
```

or

```
diff <(sed 's/*$//' file1) <(sed 's/*$//' file2)
```

(not tested, but it could work in other shells too)

**note**
the "star" is removed and from the diff point of view it has never existed.

Comment: Does not work as desired. The grep -v infact deletes any line containing an asterix and hence one temp file has tracy and another does not.I was looking for an option to just ignore the asterix.

Comment: got the question wrong... are you interested in keeping the asterisk in the final diff? if not, the fix is easy. Otherwise on the fly I have no idea, diff `-I` apart